# Count of Lines within a Range

Tags: text-processing, columns, numeric-data

I'm trying to do a count of all the values (numeric) in the third column of a file that fall within a specific range of numbers. I've found the min and max but have no idea how to do the count now. I've tried egrep, grep, awk, and more but am still confused. I'm very new to UNIX/Bash and would really appreciate any help. Thanks so much!

Comment: It will be better if you edit your question with sample input file and required output, so someone could help you. Now is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question that you want to sum up only those numbers in column 3 that are within some numeric range. Try (for sample range [9-12]):

```
awk '$3>=9 && $3<=12 {s+=$3} END {print s+0}' the_file
```